# Where's my Vox Populi badge?

Tags: support, badges

Yesterday I got the Suffrage badge and kept voting, until I got the "You have no more votes available today.  Wait n hours to vote again." (or some such)  However, it's now 20 some hours later and I see no Vox Populi badge.

Note: I realize to get Vox Populi you need several question votes.  I looked through my votes from yesterday and counted 17 question votes.  Maybe I miscounted by one or two, but I can't imagine it was that far off.

Comment: Did you happen to notice whether your vote count (at the bottom of [this page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/2317/greenmatt)) show 40 for the day?

Comment: @Jim:  No, I didn't think to look there.

Comment: Could be you maxed out your daily votes without actually hitting the required 40.

Comment: @Jim: Perhaps, but I was spreading my question votes throughout my voting.  If that's the case, I find the rules to this badge weird ... and frustrating!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it takes time to appear, but I expect that if that were your issue you would have it already.

What likely happened is that you did not meet the criteria for the badge (using the maximum possible 40 votes in one day), but still used all of your votes. You get 30 total votes per day, with an additional 10 votes that can be used on questions. The way these 10 votes works, though, is tricky. You need to use them early in the day. Once you get the countdown on your votes telling you how many you have left for the day, it's too late (but you can then determine the total you are able to cast that day). In order to get the Vox Populi badge, you need to use 40 votes, not just all of your votes.

Some explanation is [available on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/167443), with a bit [more detail here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90202/167443). I'm not sure I'm 100% clear on how it works, but I do know that if you want to get the full 40 votes in a day, you need to vote on questions early.

Comment: That must have been it - really thought I had more than enough votes on questions in the first 30.  Anyway, I got the badge for another day's voting.